# Best practices for Apple Developer signup

Tags: ios, xcode

I need to make a provisioning profile to test builds on my iOS device, to do this I need to make an Apple developer account and pay their fee.

Eventually I plan to release apps under a specific name, and I think this name may be tied to the Apple developer account name. The dilemma is that I am compelled to use a personal email for testing, and a professional email related to a business entity for releasing, and I'm not sure what to do sign up with now as I don't want to subject myself to two annual fees.

Being an individual developer, are there best practices for this sort of thing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favorite company](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/).

Comment: @gunr2171 2012 called

Comment: We're burning the apple tag, that's why this question got attention. It's really too bad that the best close reason for these are custom one which makes a comment and notifies the author.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sorry to say that if you create both accounts and want to use one for testing and one for releasing you will be subject to 2 annual fees and there is very little room to work around this. Now as far as your options go, you could go one of a few ways.

1. Create two developer accounts and pay $200 a year.
2. Consider using one account for both testing and releasing. I don't know what you concerns with doing this are, but it is perfectly acceptable to do this.
3. You test your app now using your personal account, let's say you even use this account to release your app. At any point down the road Apple has a legal entity change process (that I've been through and actually isn't that bad) to migrate your account from and individual account to a company account.

Additionally, if you are worried about there being any kind of problem deploying an app you made on your individual account on your business account, there won't be. You will have to make new developer certificates, app IDs, and provisioning profiles but that is it. Thankfully that process has become a lot more streamlined than it used to be.

Side note, If you feel it to be relevant. The name that appears as the seller of the app is defined later in the process. You can sign up using your professional email, and choose your legal entity name later on when filling out your taxation paperwork in iTunes Connect.

Comment: How long does the legal entity process change take? Does Apple require any official stamped letters or is it enough to write an email?

Answer (score 2):

You aren't compelled to use a personal e-mail for testing, you're choosing to by delaying preparing your professional e-mail address.

If you really want to delay registering your professional e-mail, then one option is to just use the Simulator, which is remarkably good - though not perfect.

If your app is successful, the additional developer subscription fee will seem like small potatoes.

Overall, this is a minor limitation, and you just need to decide what is more important to you: developing on a real device, saving the extra developer subscription, or choosing your professional e-mail address earlier than you'd planned.

Comment: I am not delaying, I am just curious if this would effect what "name" I would have on apps. For instance, I have a personal gmail for developing stuff because some clients "want an individual" instead of a company, then I have an entity for things I want a particular name associated with. Normally I just dive in and start developing but apple pretty much requires the apple id from the beginning and I'm not sure if this would have implications later down a pipeline